# VS Code - Ruby code completion with attributes from other Ruby files

Tags: ruby, visual-studio-code, intellisense, vscode-extensions, code-completion

I have an issue, I wouldn't say it's a problem at the moment, but I can see how it could turn into one in the future.

I'm following some tutorials from Ruby, so I have a folder with a bunch of different files. In one of them, I was studying **Hashes**, and they showed that I could name its keys like `:key`. No problem so far.

The issue came when I was studying **Classes** and I had to declare the class attributes, IntelliSense (I guess, maybe it is another extension) would recommend code completion with the keys I declared in that **Hashes** ruby file.

So I tested some stuff and:

- It wasn't unique to that file (of course).
- It's not just in hashes, it will recommend any type of `:attribute` I create. Whether it is classes or hashes (which is what I have tried so far), it doesn't matter.
- It isn't unique to that folder. If I have the files in different folders, with different *depths* let's say, it will still appear.

The only way I found to get rid of that was to erase the file, and that's no solution at all.

I guess my precise question is: How can I **disable** that code completion characteristic?

Comment: Yeah, I would like to disable that code completion feature, I guess is the only solution. I didn't understand your last comment, is something wrong with my question?

Comment: @byVerbel No, your question is alright. It was just a dumb remark of mine because your question said "How can I ignore" and technically that's a psychological question. I've edited your question to make that last sentence clear.

Comment: Jajaja sorry, my bad for using that word. English is not my first language. I didn't realize it could sound like that. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can ignore file or folder in code completion by adding it to `files.watcherExclude` setting.

Files must be closed in editor: if ignored file is open, it will still be used for autocomplete.

[image]